# Matching unbalanced parentheses

Tags: brackets, l3regex

In `xparse` `r` arguments are specified as `r<token1><token2>`. I'm trying to regex-check whether an expression matches that (ignoring the `r` for now), with =`\{` and =`>`. The example below returns F whereas it should return T. Any suggestion?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
    
%\regex_const:Nn\c__erw_regex{\cB\{.+\cE>}
\regex_const:Nn\c__erw_regex{\{.+\cO>}
\regex_match:NnTF
\c__erw_regex
%{{Hello>} % ERROR Runaway arg
{\{Hello>} 
{T}
{F}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you hoping to do something like `\foo{xxx>` and get `#1` as `xxx`? If so, you are out of luck: TeX requires that `{` is matched by `}` (more formally, it requires that each catcode 1 token is matched by a catcode 2 one: these are normally `{` and `}`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characters `\{` are used in a regex to match a `{`. You want instead to match `\{`, a single TeX token.

In general, in order to match a control sequence, say `\foo`, which is not considered by `l3regex` as consisting of four characters, but is a single object (token), you'd use `\c{foo}`. But here one cannot use `\c{{}`, because it would be unbalanced. No problem! Use `\c{\{}` and all will be good.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\regex_const:Nn \c__erw_bracerangle_regex { \c{\{}.+>}
\regex_match:NnTF \c__erw_bracerangle_regex {\{Hello>} {T} {F}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

This will print “T”.

Note that you don't need `\cO>` in the search expression, because `l3regex` is “category code agnostic” when examining characters in the input list of tokens. You may need `\cO` or similar prefixes in the replace expression, though, otherwise characters would be assigned category code 12.